# Using Excel VBA to select onchange value in JavaScript web

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, web, onchange

I am very new to VBA, I've been tried many times to use Excel VBA to select the value on a website, but it doesn't work. Below is the code I use.

Actually I don't know how to get the elements since it has no "id" or "name" tag.

```html
Sub GetFinanceData()

Dim URL As String

URL = "http://stock.finance.sina.com.cn/hkstock/finance/00001.html"

Set myIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With myIE
.navigate URL
.Visible = True

Do While .Busy = True Or .readyState <> 4
Loop
DoEvents

.Document.parentWindow.execScript "selectData(zero);", "JavaScript"

End With

End Sub
```

Below is the HTML code, I want to change the option value to "zero" when open the website, can anybody help to check and advise what VBA code I can use to get the value "zero"? Thanks a lot in advance!

[image]

```html
 <a name="a1" id="a1"></a>
   <div class="part02">
      <div class="sub01">
          <div class="sub01_tt fblue">
              <span class=" selected"><a href="#a1" target="_self">重要财务指标</a></span>
              <span class=""><a href="#a2" target="_self">资产负债表</a></span>
              <span class=""><a href="#a3" target="_self">现金流量表</a></span>
              <span class=""><a href="#a4" target="_self">综合损益表</a></span>
              <em class="rt">报表类型:<select class="fgrey" style="width:100px;" interface="getFinanceStandardForjs?symbol=$symbol&financeStanderd=" table="tableGetFinanceStandard" onchange="selectData(this);">
                <option value="all" >全部</option>
                <option value="zero" >年报</option>
                <option value="1" >中报</option>
                <option value="2" >一季报</option>
                <option value="3" >三季报</option>
            </select></em>
        </div>
        <div class="sub01_cc">
             <div class="sub01_c">
                              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"  class="tab05">
                    <tbody id="tableGetFinanceStandard">
                     <tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, addressing a form element by its HTML `name` or `id` is sometimes favorable but in your example, you can use the **getElementsByTagName()** method to address `select` tags even though they have no name or id.

Below code will set all `select` drop downs to "zero". I tested briefly and it worked fine.

```
Sub GetFinanceData()
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "http://stock.finance.sina.com.cn/hkstock/finance/00001.html"

    Set myIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With myIE
        .navigate URL
        .Visible = True

        Do While .Busy = True Or .readyState <> 4
            Loop
        DoEvents

        Set selectItems = myIE.document.getElementsByTagName("select")
        For Each i In selectItems
            i.Value = "zero"
            i.FireEvent ("onchange")
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi nhee, thanks for your quick response, the cell value in the selection box had changed to zero, but I found that the data in the table did not follow to change, is it due to something like "click action"? Would you please help to check? I could not post the screen capture coz I don't have enough reputation in this forum.

Comment: Hey there. Good point. You need to add `i.FireEvent ("onchange")` to the code after setting the "zero" value. I've updated it in my solution. Now the numbers update, as well. Does it work for you?

Comment: Wow, excellent, it works! You are really a genius, man~ It's cool! I really really admire you, haha, I've been struggling for this a few days, OK, next step I should start to study how to extract these data to excel. Any button to choose your answer as the best answer here?

Comment: My pleasure. There should be a "check" symbol on the left of the first paragraph of my answer, click it and the answer will be marked selected. Thanks. For your next challenge, read the HTML code first, I think they have some `id`s in the tags of the data tables.

Comment: Hi, I found the data downloaded into excel are not fully changed, I think it is because I use this "Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop" code between clicking the button and starting to download. Could you advise whether this affects the websites tully loaded or not?

Comment: Mmh. These commands actually wait for the page to be fully loaded before continuing. In your case, the `FireEvent`s are possibly being triggered faster than the Internet Explorer can update the page. What you could try is to insert `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))` after the `FireEvent` line. This will make the macro wait 2 seconds before continuing and give the IE sufficient time to process the onchange events.

Comment: Can you see whether all tables are updated in the IE window? How long does it take after you change the drop downs by hand? That's the amount of seconds the Excel macro should wait, as well.

Comment: I go to change it by hand, seems less than 1 second. So, it means the more seconds to wait, the more successful, right? Let me try to take 4 seconds to test.

Comment: Hi, I want to thank you again! Once I raise the number of second, it works perfectly!

Comment: Hi, buddy, I met a new problem, do you have time to have a look? This link:         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29897809/excel-vba-add-and-name-the-multiple-sheets-according-to-a-list-of-names-string

Comment: Hi，nhee，could help to answer this question？http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947398/get-web-data-by-getelementsbytagname-innertext

Answer (score 1):

**CSS selector:**

Use a CSS selector to target `option[value='zero']`

That says `option` tag having attribute `value` with value of `'zero'`. `"[]"` means attribute.

---

**CSS query:**

[image: css query]

---

**VBA:**

You apply the selector with `querySelector` method of `document` i.e.

To simply select then

```
ie.document.querySelector("option[value='zero']").Selected = True
```

If additional event firing needs to be triggered:

```
ie.document.querySelector("option[value='zero']").FireEvent "onchange"
```