# Excel VBA add and name multiple sheets according to a list of names

Tags: string, excel, list, vba, variables

I made a VBA script which can download table data according to a list of website. Now the problem is: how to name the sheets according to a list of names. This code already contains the add sheets function, and the list of sheet names is in the sheet "Stocks", starting from cell B1. Thanks in advance!

```
Sub GetFinanceData()
For x = 1 To 5
Dim URL As String, elemCollection As Object
Dim t As Integer, r As Integer, c As Integer

Worksheets("Stocks").Select
Worksheets("Stocks").Activate

'Open IE and Go to the Website

URL = "http://stock.finance.sina.com.cn/hkstock/finance/00001.html"
URL = Cells(x, 1)

Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = x

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .navigate URL
    .Visible = True

    Do While .Busy = True Or .readyState <> 4
        Loop
    DoEvents

'Select the Report Type

Set selectItems = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")
    For Each i In selectItems
        i.Value = "zero"
        i.FireEvent ("onchange")
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    Next i

    Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K500").ClearContents

'Find and Get the First Table Data

Set elemCollection = .Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
For t = 0 To (elemCollection.Length - 4)
    For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
        For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
    Next c
    Next r
    Next t

'Find and Get the Second Table Data

Set elemCollection = .Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
For t = 1 To (elemCollection.Length - 3)
    For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
        For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
ActiveSheet.Cells(r + 19, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
    Next c
    Next r
    Next t

'Find and Get the Third Table Data

Set elemCollection = .Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
For t = 2 To (elemCollection.Length - 2)
    For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
        For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
ActiveSheet.Cells(r + 48, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
    Next c
    Next r
    Next t

'Find and Get the Fourth Table Data

Set elemCollection = .Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
For t = 3 To (elemCollection.Length - 1)
    For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
        For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
ActiveSheet.Cells(r + 61, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
    Next c
    Next r
    Next t

    End With

    ' cleaning up memory

    IE.Quit

    Next x

  End Sub
```

Comment: Hello again. Sorry to ask, but where in here are you adding worksheets?

Comment: Add worksheet after the end of current worksheet

Comment: The script works now after the following changes:  'Open IE and Go to the Website
    
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .navigate URL
        .Visible = True

        Do While .Busy = True Or .readyState <> 4
            Loop
        DoEvents
    
    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = _
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stocks").Range("B" & x).Value    
    'Select the Report Type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = _
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stocks").Range("B" & x).Value
```

Comment: Hi Miss Palmer, I forgot to tell that value 'x' is already used for the list of URL...Does this affect?

Comment: It affects in the sense that you need to call that variable something else. Just replace it with something else and wrap the whole thing in a `For Each` loop going through your sheet names in column B.

Comment: if for every URL, you want to create a new worksheet (e.g. if they're named side by side), then it should work like it is. You could even simplify it and just state the name as Cells(x,2) if the list of worksheet names is alongside the list of URLs.

Comment: Hi nhee and Miss Palmer, in the first test, I just changed the script with what Miss Palmer posted, it does not work, so I move the 'add worksheet part' immediately after the IE opened, it works now! Thanks a lot! But may I  know why I cannot put add sheets first before open IE...

Comment: that doesn't make sense to me. but glad you've got it working.

Comment: Hahaha, I just wonder how you guys are so good at VBA, are you an Engineer or computer science students?

Comment: Lol. I am an engineering graduate actually. Working in finance now though. Just answer some questions when I'm bored at work :P Still got a lot to learn!

Comment: Hi Palmer, could you help me on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947398/get-web-data-by-getelementsbytagname-innertext